# Read Value of variable from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a few strings in a file that look like:

```
line1    <img alt="Powered by MediaWiki" height="31" src="/static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png" srcset="/static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_132x47.png 1.5x, /static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_176x62.png 2x" width="88"/>
line2    '<img alt="" class="wp-image-141 size-large" height="591" sizes="(max-width: 788px) 100vw, 788px" src="https://alessandrorossini.org/wp-content/2018/07/20180619_151349-1024x768.jpg" srcset="https://alessandrorossini.org/wp-content/2018/07/20180619_151349-1024x768.jpg 1024w, https://alessandrorossini.org/wp-content/2018/07/20180619_151349-300x225.jpg 300w, https://alessandrorossini.org/wp-content/2018/07/20180619_151349-788x591.jpg 788w" width="788"/>
```

I want to read the value of height in each line (ex: 31 in line 1 and 591 in line 2).

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What was it? Why didn't it work? Either way, look up Python BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Various ways to get what you are after. Here is one to look into: [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse html, in which case i suggest a proper html-parser, for example https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/. If thats not sufficient i would suggest looking into https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code below run, I placed your two lines into a file called `file_name.html`. Here are two ways of extracting the value of `height`.

**With BeautifulSoup**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file_name.html', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html5lib')
    for img_tag in soup.find_all('img'):
        print(img_tag.get('height'))
```

**With regular expressions**

```
import re

with open('file_name.html', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    regex = '(height=")(\d*)(")'  # 2nd regex group captures the value of height
    heights = [re.search(regex, l).group(2) for l in lines]
    print(heights)
```

Note that this particular Regex example only catches the first `height` value of each line.